# Check if boolean value present in nested object

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a JSON column and the data stored looks like:

```json
{"results":{"made":true,"cooked":true,"eaten":true}}
{"results":{"made":true,"cooked":true,"eaten":false}}
{"results":{"made":true,"eaten":true,"a":false,"b":true,"c":false}, "more": {"ignore":true}}
```

I need to find all rows where 1+ values in `$.results` is `false`.

I tried using `JSON_CONTAINS()` but didn't find a way to get it to compare to a boolean JSON value, or to look at all values in `$.results`.

This needs to work with MySQL 5.7 but if it's not possible I will accept a MySQL 8+ answer.

Comment: So, what is the Expected result as per the given sample data in your Problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the way for to search for a JSON `true/false/null` value using JSON functions - in practice these values are treated as string-type values during the search with JSON_CONTAINS, JSON_SEARCH, etc.

Use regular expression for the checking. Something like

```sql
SELECT id, 
       JSON_PRETTY(jsondata)
FROM test
WHERE jsondata REGEXP '"results": {[^}]+: false.*}';
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=052b3f733c48a630e72be0d2c6073227)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply search the `JSON_EXTRACT` using the `LIKE` condition this way.

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(json_dict, '$.results') LIKE '%: false%';`

Check this [DB FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nZM9d9ZB78qB2tfLzB63az/0)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the pattern matching in other answers, is to extract all values from `$.results` and check each entry with a helper table with running numbers

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.id, v.json_value
FROM (
 SELECT id, json_value, JSON_EXTRACT(json_value, '$.results.*') value_array
 FROM json_table
) v
JOIN seq ON seq.n < JSON_LENGTH(v.value_array)
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(v.value_array, CONCAT('$[', seq.n, ']')) = false
```

[Here is the demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ux6CfyzMAc4BKtTrvh3F5s/0)